# Does Add-MpPreference work with Windows 8.1?

Tags: powershell, windows-defender

I have a powershell script that adds file exclusions to Windows Defender on a computer running Windows 10.

But I run the same script with Windows 8.1 but I get an error message saying:

> Add-MpPreference : The 'Add-MpPreference' command was found in the
>   module 'Defender', but the module could not be loaded. For more
>   information, run 'Import-Module Defender'. At line:1 char:1
>   + Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "C:\Temp"
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Add-MpPreference:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule

What can I do to make it work with Windows 8/8.1?

Comment: The error message already tells you want to do: `For more information, run 'Import-Module Defender'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with WMI class. I remember there was WMI class exist for defender.
Use some WMI tools to explore those classes.

Comment: Can you send me a link for that?

Comment: So can you give me an example. If I want to add the folder "C:\Temp" and the process "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\test.exe" as exclusions to WD, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: Sure ,will check and let you know

Comment: Try this :

$DefPreference = Get-WmiObject -Namespace ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\Defender -Class MSFT_MpPreference -ComputerName <ComputerName> -ErrorAction Stop

$DefPreference.ExclusionPath = "C:\Temp"

$DefPreference.ExclusionProcess = 'C:\Program Files\Adobe\<Exe Name>'

Comment: Do you mind putting that into your answer. Just for better formatting...

Comment: I would like to be able to run this script on any computer. In here I need to specify the computer name: `-ComputerName <ComputerName>`. Is there some kind of wildcard to be able to run on it any computer?

Comment: You can use advanced funtions to pass multiple computers.

Comment: I would recommend you to search in Google about powershell advanced funtions

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can copy `MSFT_MpWDOScan.cdxml` from a Windows 10 / 2016 to `C:\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\modules\Defender\`

Comment: Upvoted (to balance the one downvote), because this is indeed an [official resolution option from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4497578/windows-8-1-windows-powershell-cannot-import-windows-defender-module)

Comment: Yeah, works great but correct path is C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Defender. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft broke Defender module in 2017-04 Monthly Rollup and later.
Below is C:\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\modules\Defender\Defender.psd1.

```
@{
GUID = 'C46BE3DC-30A9-452F-A5FD-4BF9CA87A854'
Author="Microsoft Corporation"
CompanyName="Microsoft Corporation"
Copyright="ｩ Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved."
ModuleVersion = '1.0'
NestedModules = @( 'MSFT_MpComputerStatus.cdxml',
                   'MSFT_MpPreference.cdxml',
                   'MSFT_MpThreat.cdxml',
                   'MSFT_MpThreatCatalog.cdxml',
                   'MSFT_MpThreatDetection.cdxml',
                   'MSFT_MpScan.cdxml',
                   'MSFT_MpSignature.cdxml',
                   'MSFT_MpWDOScan.cdxml')


AliasesToExport = @()
FunctionsToExport = @( 'Get-MpPreference',
                       'Set-MpPreference',
                       'Add-MpPreference',
                       'Remove-MpPreference',
                       'Get-MpComputerStatus',
                       'Get-MpThreat',
                       'Get-MpThreatCatalog',
                       'Get-MpThreatDetection',
                       'Start-MpScan',
                       'Update-MpSignature',
                       'Remove-MpThreat',
                       'Start-MpWDOScan')

PowerShellVersion = '3.0'
HelpInfoUri="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=390762"
}
```

**MSFT_MpWDOScan.cdxml** and **Start-MpWDOScan** isn't present in Windows 8.1.
Removing them works again. (This file is protected by TrustedInstaller.)